# how to filter an array by multiple properties and get filtered array length in angular binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an array object and i want filter that array by multiple properties and get filtered array object length in my html angular binding for checkbox check/uncheck condition as below:

```
    myArray=[
                {"ID":1,"StatusID":0},
                {"ID":2,"StatusID":1},
                {"ID":3,"StatusID":0}];

<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="myArray|filter:{ID:2}).length==1" />

my expected result like 
if (myArray.ID=2 && myArray.StatusID=1).length==1 
then checkbox is checked 
else unchecked
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="(myArray|filter:{ID:2,StatusID:1}).length==1" />
```